# Javascript contenteditable on innerhtml created object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I have this code that is supposed to create a new list item (li) that is editable (`contenteditable="true"`):

```
var currenthtml = document.getElementById("0").innerHTML;
var newhtml = currenthtml + '<li class="object" contenteditable="true">...</li>';
```

The object is created and visible, the purehtml for `#0` after editing is:

```
<div id="0">
    <li class="object" contenteditable="true">First object</li>
</div>
```

To save the content, I have the following helper:

```
function SaveObject(html) {
    localStorage.setItem("obj", html);
}
```

which is supposed to be called because of:

```
$('li[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '');
        $(this).blur();

        var html = document.getElementById("0").innerHTML;
        SaveObject(html);

        return false;
    }
});
```

(I'll change it to save on other cases, but this is the current saving method.)

but when I edit a new item and try to save, it is not saved the text. It stays there temporarily, but then changes to the default "...". How can I make this work?

The #0 is set this way

```
if(localStorage.getItem("obj") != null) {
    document.getElementById("0").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("obj");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's several steps you should check:

1. in your `keydown` handler, check the value of `html`:

   ```
   $('li[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
           document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '');
           $(this).blur();

           var html = document.getElementById("0").innerHTML;
           console.log(html); // is the value equal to what is expected?
           SaveObject(html);

           return false;
       }
   });
   ```
2. Second, try to check if it is saved to local storage directly after you have saved:

   ```
   $('li[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 13) {
           document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, '');
           $(this).blur();

           var html = document.getElementById("0").innerHTML;
           SaveObject(html);
           console.log(localStorage.getItem("obj")); // is the value equal to what was saved?

           return false;
       }
   });
   ```
3. If the two answers are "yes", check out the value after reloading of your page: just type `localStorage.getItem("obj")` in your console.
4. Finally, if the data is still there, make sure that you actually add it back to DOM. You haven't shown us the code which adds list items with the saved data to the page.